# Disadvantages of having a virtual machine with a different file system than host

Tags: virtual-machine, ext3, filesystems, vmware-server, xfs

I have a server with VMware Server 2 configured to host several virtual machines. I chose XFS as the filesystem for this main server because of his great handling of large files.

But I want the virtual machines to have EXT3 filesystem. My question is:

Are there any drawbacks/disadvantages of having a different filesystem from the host in virtual guests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not particularly. Use the best file system for the application. There is a layer of abstraction in there anyway since the VM server has it's own file format.